# How to iterate over a file and put the all the id values into an list [Python]

Tags: python, arrays, json, data-analysis

```
{'asin': '0756029929', 'description': 'Spanish Third-year Pin, 1 inch in diameter.  Set of 10.', 'title': 'Spanish Third-year Pin Set of 10', 'price': 11.45, 'imUrl': 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51AqSOl7qLL._SY300_.jpg', 'salesRank': {'Toys & Games': 918374}, 'categories': [['Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry', 'Novelty, Costumes & More', 'Novelty', 'Clothing']]}
{'asin': '0756029104', 'description': 'Viva Espaol pin, 1 x 1 inch. Set of 10.', 'title': 'Viva Espanol Pins Set of 10', 'price': 11.45, 'imUrl': 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51By%2BZpF9DL._SY300_.jpg', 'salesRank': {'Home &amp; Kitchen': 2651070}, 'categories': [['Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry', 'Novelty, Costumes & More', 'Novelty', 'Clothing']]}
{'asin': '0839933363', 'description': 'This necklace from the popular manga and anime series, Death Note. The necklace\'s charm is black and silver with the text, "Death Note" upon it. The approx. length of the necklace is 12"Dimension & Measurement:Length: Approx. 12"', 'title': 'Death Note Anime Manga: Cross Logo necklace', 'imUrl': 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51f0HkHssyL._SY300_.jpg', 'salesRank': {'Toys & Games': 1350779}, 'categories': [['Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry', 'Novelty, Costumes & More', 'Costumes & Accessories']]}
{'asin': '1304567583', 'description': 'pink bikini swimwear glow in the dark fashion', 'title': 'Pink Bikini Swimwear Glow in the Dark Fashion', 'price': 19.99, 'imUrl': 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41pS%2B98jhlL._SY300_.jpg', 'categories': [['Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry', 'Novelty, Costumes & More', 'Costumes & Accessories', 'Costumes']]}
{'asin': '1304567613', 'description': 'Bikini Swimwear glow in the dark fashion blue', 'title': 'Bikini Swimwear Blue Glow in the Dark Fashion', 'price': 29.99, 'imUrl': 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41ZNIUvYkyL._SY300_.jpg', 'categories': [['Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry', 'Novelty, Costumes & More', 'Costumes & Accessories', 'Costumes']]}
{'asin': '1465014578', 'title': '2013 Desk Pad Calendar', 'imUrl': 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51NadiHHHsL._SX342_.jpg', 'related': {'also_bought': ['B009SDBX0Q', 'B009DCUY1G'], 'bought_together': ['B009SDBX0Q', 'B009DCUY1G']}, 'salesRank': {'Clothing': 505645}, 'categories': [['Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry', 'Novelty, Costumes & More', 'Band & Music Fan', 'Accessories']]}
{'asin': '1620574128', 'related': {'also_bought': ['B0015KET88', 'B00004WKPP', 'B000F8T8U0', 'B000F8V736', 'B000F8VAOM', 'B0015KGFQM', 'B003U6P4OS', '1564519392', 'B000F8XF8Q', 'B0042SR3E2', 'B004PBLVDU', 'B000G3LR9Y', 'B0006PKZBI', 'B0007PC9CK', 'B001G98DS0', 'B001UFWJLW', 'B003S8XLWA', '0486214834', '1609964713', 'B000P1PVMQ', '0590308572', 'B000QDZY52', '1564514188', 'B0006PKZ7W', 'B000T2YKIM', 'B000QDTWF0', 'B000FA6DXS', 'B0007P94ZA', 'B000WA3FKU', 'B00004WKPU', 'B000F8XF68', 'B004DJ51JE', '
```

I have this file and want to put all the values of asins into there own list, Here is what I have so far but I just can't figure out how to do this or what is the best way to do it because the file has an extension of .json but it is not in the format of vaild json hence why im trying to do it like a normal text file.

```
with open('File.json', "r") as f:
    for line in f:
         if 'asin' in line:
        #Code that gets the values of asins
         clothing_ids.append(#then add them values to clothing_ids)

print(clothing_ids)
```

Comment: You probably want to look at an actual JSON parser.

Comment: @MadPhysicist But when I've tried this I just get an error because of how the file is structured, it moans that its not vaild json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file is guaranteed untainted, you could `eval` each line:

```
with open('File.json', "r") as f:
    asins = [eval(line)['asin'] for line in f]
```

---

Here is the same code, using @Ajax1234's `ast.literal_eval()`, to avoid issue with tainted files, but using my list comprehension, which evaluates each line individually, and so doesn't store the whole dataset as a temporary.

```
import ast

with open('File.json', "r") as f:
    asins = [ast.literal_eval(line)['asin'] for line in f]
```

---

For your comment-based bonus question, getting a list of all "also_bought" items, including duplicates:

```
import ast

also_bought = []
asins = []
with open('File.json', "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        item = ast.literal_eval(line)
        asins.append(item['asin'])
        if 'related' in item:
           related = item['related']
           if 'also_bought' in related:
              also_bought.extend(related['also_bought'])
```

Comment: Thanks! this worked! but could you explain how it works a bit for me please?

Comment: Each line looks like a valid python expression.  The `eval` function interprets the string as if it was python code, so that the string `{ 'asin': '01234' }` will return a python `dict` object.  Then `['asin']` extracts the "asin" entry from the dictionary.  The `[ ...  for line in f]` is standard python list comprehension ... it loops over all lines in the file `f`, calling each line `line`, producing the list.

Comment: Oh, and while it works, don't use it.  Use the `ast.literal_eval` version, by @Ajax1234 ... or else when someone taints the file, and puts actual code in it, you'll execute their (probably malicious) code.

Comment: @AJNeufield That method doesn't work for me though I get an invalid syntax error

Comment: @AJNeufield Okay thank you for that, one last question, if you look at my data file again how could I get all the 'also_bought' values in an array one item at a time? hope that makes sense.

Comment: Sorry - that isn't clear at all.  Did you want the also_bought items listed along with the original asin values?  Did you want an array of arrays?  Or all the data in one long array, with or without duplicates.  You probably shouldn't answer that in these comments, but rather post a new question with exactly what you want.

Comment: I have to wait 90 minutes to post another question, Ill try explaining it better. I want to put all the values of also_bought into there own list, So at the end I will want a new list with the also bought values for every item in the file @AJNeufeld

Answer (score 2):

Use list comprehension with `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast
data = ast.literal_eval(open('File.json').read())
asins = [i['asin'] for i in data]
```

Comment: I get an invalid syntax error when I try and use this.

Comment: File "<unknown>", line 2
    {'asin': '0681256036', 'related': {'also_viewed': ['B005TLMG0M', 'B002R0DRR4', 'B005VQ0NBY', 'B001G5ZCBA', 'B00AI7VZTK', 'B0069S2DKW', 'B005TKZE1Q', 'B001G5ZCC4', 'B002R0DOSQ', 'B001PMUUPC', 'B005TL3RM8', 'B005TLNETE', 'B009O0H11I', 'B002C0F3RQ', 'B00AVQWCQI', 'B001HX4MCG', 'B00FF0VCAW', 'B00946ZOT8', 'B002WGHXI2']}, 'title': 'Twilight Saga: New Moon Alice Chocker Necklace Wearable Prop Replica', 'price': 17.59, 'salesRank': {'Toys & Games': 674790}]}
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Jake123 your dictionary itself contains invalid Python syntax. The final bracket (`]`), in the example you posted above, is not necessary.